# how to copy specific cells of data (skipping blank cells) into another worksheet into next blank row?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, data-manipulation

I have a spreadsheet that survey's equipment condition for multiple types of equipment (see Data Input example).  For each row I need the equipment under the columns header "E1" and "E1C" copy/pasted into another worksheet ("ET target" in example) with the ID number and then "E2" & "E2C" copy pasted into next blank row with the same ID. keep doing this for each nonblank cells in each row.

Data Input example

[image: Data Input example]

The "Data Output Example" image can help explain what I mean.

[image: Data Ouput Example for 1 Type of Equipment]

I've tried a few things and read quite a few posts, but havent found anything that i could combine together to work. Below is what im working on currently, but is far from complete.

EDIT:  new code so far.  works, but would like to learn how to loop  and skip blanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet


    'range is B:L.  B8:L8 empty so skipped
    'next is B9:L9.  skip J9:L9 becuase empty
    Sheets("Source").Range("B9:C9,A9").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("D9:E9,A9").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("D9:E9,A9").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("F9:G9,A9").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("H9:I9,A9").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    'Skip B10:L10 empty.  Next is B11:L11.  Skip F11:L11 becuase empty
    Sheets("Source").Range("B11:C11,A11").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("D11:E11,A11").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    'Skip B12:L14 becuase empty.  Next is B15:L15.  skip H15:L15 becuase empty
    Sheets("Source").Range("B15:C15,A15").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("D15:E15,A15").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("F15:G15,A15").Copy
    Sheets("ET target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    'Repeat for upto 200 rows.

'Same steps but for other Equipment.
'Range is M:AB. Skip
Sheets("Source").Range("M9:N9,A9").Copy
Sheets("UT target").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the `SkipBlanks` argument of the `PasteSpecial`function ?

It would look like something like this with your code :

```
Sheets("Source").Range("B9:C9,A9").Copy
Sheets("ET target").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, SkipBlanks:=True
```

See the [Range.PasteSpecial method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) for more information.